# How do I use GWT Google Web Toolkit in my own Java project without GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, resin

I would like to see if I can use GWT in my already existing Servlet-site using the Resin web-server, however I am having problems locating any decent guides that can help me out

Does anyone have a hands-on tutorial/guide on how to use GWT outside an "GWT project" or without using Google App Engine (GAE)?

I am still using Eclipse and have GWT plugins enabled and added the GWT support for the project, but I am unsure how to connect all the components together without using GAE.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you dont need GAE for GWT. I have been using GWT nearly for two years. I do not need to install GAE sdk..

I recommend your to read [this document](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideRPCDeployment) . It explains how to configure application servers to integrate with gwt..